# Printing 1D and 2D Arrays Side-by-Side

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java (coding in general) so I'm sorry for the mistakes in advance. I'm sure there's probably an easier way to do this but I can't figure it out.
I feel like I'm making a very obvious mistake, too.

This is what I've been asked to do:

> Write a program that will input 10 student names in random order and
>   his / her corresponding 3 project scores.  These data will be read
>   into 2 separate arrays: an array of strings to hold the names, and a
>   2-dimensional array of numbers to hold the scores.  You may input the
>   data from keyboard or from a text file.
>
> Output the input data in a table form.
>
> Using Selection Sort, rearrange the random student names
>   alphabetically.  The corresponding scores would obviously need to
>   follow the sorted order.  **Output the sorted names and scores in a
>   table form.**
>
> Using Binary Search, your program will allow user to input a name. 
>   Your program will output the name and its corresponding 3 project
>   scores.
>
> For each of the 3 projects, output the name of the student(s) who
>   scored the highest mark.

The part in bold is where I'm stuck. I compile and run normally but when it comes to printing the table, only the last set of 3 numbers that were inputted would appear, for example (yes the formatting needs to be worked on so that it's a table, this is just a temp format until I've got this problem solved)
    [This is what I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjv0p.png) The rest of the names were cut off but they all print the same scores anyways.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**Write a program that will input 10 students names
* in random order and their corresponding 3 project scores.
* Data will be read into 2 separate arrays: an array of strings
* for the names and a 2D array for the scores.
* Output input data in table form
*For each of the 3 projects, output the name of the student(s) who scored
the highest mark.
**/

public class NameAndGrades
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
   //Scanner object to allow user input
     Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

   //This array will store the names of the students
     String[] names = new String[10];

   //This 2D array will store the 3 project scores
     int[][] scores = new int [10][3];


      //Ask user to input the student names
       System.out.println("Enter the 10 student names: ");

       for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
       {
         System.out.print("Student " + (index +1) + ": ");
         names[index] = scnr.nextLine();
       }


       selectionSort(names);


      //Will print the names alphabetically
      //THIS WILL BE DELETED LATER, IT WAS JUST TO CHECK IF IT DID ITS JOB

      System.out.println("The students' names in alphabetical order: ");

       for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
       {
         System.out.println( names[i] ); 
       }


     //Ask user to enter the corresponding project scores

       System.out.println("Enter the 3 project "
                          + "scores for each student: ");

        for (int row = 0; row < scores.length; row++)
        {
         for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
           {
            for (int col = 0; col < scores[row].length; col++)
             {
              System.out.print(names[i] + " Test "
                               + (col +1) + ": ");
              scores[row][col] = scnr.nextInt();
             }
            }
            break;
          }


     //PRINT NAMES AND SCORES SIDE BY SIDE
     //MAKE TABLE HEADING HERE
       for (int row = 0; row < scores.length; row++)
        {  
         for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
         {
          System.out.println(names[i] + " grades: ");
           for (int col = 0; col < scores[row].length; col++)
            {
             System.out.print(scores[row][col] + " ");
            }
           System.out.println();
         }break;
        }
   }



/**Selection sort method made to sort the student names in
* alphabetical order.
@param names names of students
@return the names organized alphabetically
**/

public static String[] selectionSort(String[] names)
 {
  for (int index = 0; index < names.length - 1; ++index)
   {
     int minIndex = index;
      for (int j = index + 1; j < names.length; ++j)
       {
        if (names[j].compareTo(names[minIndex]) < 0)
         {
          minIndex = j;
         }
       }
  String temp = names[index];
  names[index] = names[minIndex];
  names[minIndex] = temp;
     }
   return (names);
  }
}
```

How can I edit this so that I have the correct scores for each student?
Thank you in advance for the help!!

Comment: What's the table supposed to look like?

Comment: One way to accomplish this would be rather than return a string array, have your `selectionSort()` perform operations on the array directly and have int array mimick actions performed on string array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that scores array and names array are related. Hence, as you have done, input the names, sort them and then ask user to enter the scores. This means that you dont have to juggle the scores around while sorting the names. Which implies that

```
names[i] has the scores in scores[i][0...2]

for(int i = 0; i < names.length; ++i)
    print names[i] + " : " + scores[i][0] + ", " + scores[i][1] + ", " + scores[i][2] ;
```

[See here](http://ideone.com/AMRVZJ).

Also, you may want to used fixed widths. Lookup output formatters to format the table properly.

Ideally you would want to create a class which contains the name and the three marks as data and implement a custom `Comparator` (which compares the names w.r.t dictionary order), then just store the list in an `ArrayList` and sort it.

**Edit**
From your question (and as mentioned in the comment), you would want to take the input first and then sort, which means you need to juggle around the scores in the same way as you would do for the names i.e. if `names[i]` and `names[j]` are swapped, so should `scores[i]` and `scores[j]`.

Comment: Pretty sure the objective is to sort the data *after* all of the data is entered. Trying to input names, sort names, and then ask for scores doesn't fulfill that objective.

Comment: Yes I think so too. But my code does minimal surgery on the OP's code. Adding an edit.

Comment: Thanks much for your response! (and sorry for getting back so late)but since you answered my question on how to format the table I'll accept your answer. 
I do have more questions on this but I'll ask on a separate post.
Thank you again!